# LG freezer door expands and produces a bulge after power outage

Tags: doors, refrigerator, freezer

We recently had a power outage of more than few days.
After a few days of no power, the freezer door (inner part) expanded and produced a bulge on the lower right area. 
Because of the bulge, the freezer door cannot be closed properly.
Pls see pic below for more clarity.

Few questions:

1. Anyone know why this happened?
2. Can anyone guide me on how to fix it?
3. How can this be prevented in the future?

Thank you

[image: LG freezer bulge]

Comment: Can you disassemble the bulging part to see what's causing it to bulge?

Comment: did this appear after the power was restored and the freezer was cold again?

Comment: @jay613, there seems to be a resistance in the bulging area. My suspicion is that the insulator foam is the one causing the bulge. I cannot seem to find a guide on how to remove the inner linings and see whats underneath. But will continue to look for a guide.

Comment: @rtaft it started to bulge while there is still a power outage. Freezer has not yet been turned on ever since the outage. Also during the outage, door was closed for a few days. Then we opened it to dry it out then bulge started to appear

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that during the outage, water got in there and stayed. When the power came back on, it froze and expanded.

The solution is to empty both fridge and freezer, pull the plug, let it thaw for a while, and then take apart the freezer door to remove any remaining icebergs. (Last step is optional if you can let it thaw and drain for a really long time.)

Comment: When power outage started, door was closed for a few days then we opened it to dry it out. Thats when it started to bulge. So i dont think it was frozen water. After the bulge, it cannot be closed anymore. 

There is some sort of resistance in the bulging area. I suspect its the insulator foam. 
We have not yet turned it on since then.